# Scala Pattern: For Comprehension that Yields a Future[A]

Tags: scala, future, for-comprehension

What is the pattern used in Scala to deal with the scenario:

You have a bunch of futures (they can be whatever, but for the sake of example...)

```
val aF = Future { true }
val bF = Future { Option(3) }
val cF = Future { myObject }
```

and you have some function that returns a future

```
def fooF: Future[SomeObject]
```

I want to do something like:

```
for {
    a <- aF
    b <- bF
    c <- cF
} yield {
    if (a) {
        // do stuff with b & c
        fooF
    } else {
        Future.successful(SomeObject)
    }
}
```

I want to return a value of `Future[SomeObject]`, but I call fooF inside of the yield statement, I will get a `Future[Future[SomeObject]]`

Comment: Assign the "inner" Future in the for using `<-` before yield. Try to refactor with nested flatMap to understand.

Comment: @cchantep won't that trigger the future before I use it though? I don't want the future to begin executing until I call it...which may be never

Comment: You should read more about for comprehension/flatMap/Future

Comment: @clo_jur futures are triggered at evaluation anyway, so it will execute at this point, whether you put it in the for or in the yield. The only way to delay execution is to declare this whole `Future[SomeObject]` as `lazy val` or `def`, but it will also delay all the other futures in the computation (unless they were started beforehand).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is another solution :

```
def doStuffWith(a: A, b: B, c: C): Future[SomeObject] = if (a) {
  // do stuff with b & c
  fooF
} else Future.successful(SomeObject)

for {
  a <- aF
  b <- bF
  c <- cF
  d <- doStuffWith(a, b, c)
} yield d
```

As discussed in @laughedelic answer, this is a subjective view, but I believe this way to be more readable, and maintainable (taking out the function always to unit test it, for instance).

Answer (score -2):

- In Scala 2.12 `Future` has a [`flatten`](http://scala-lang.org/api/2.12.0/scala/concurrent/Future.html#flatten[S](implicitev:<:<[T,scala.concurrent.Future[S]]):scala.concurrent.Future[S]) method:

  > Creates a new future with one level of nesting flattened, this method is equivalent to flatMap(identity).

  So you can write `for { ... } yield { ... } flatten`.
- In Scala <2.12 you can achieve the same with `flatMap(identity)` (as mentioned above)

---

An alternative solution is to use `flatMap` instead of for-comprehension:

```
aF.flatMap { a =>
  if (a) {
    (bF zip cF).flatMap { (b, c) =>
      // do stuff with b & c
      fooF
    }
  } else 
    Future.successful(SomeObject)
  }
}
```

Comment: The flatten should not occur is the case

Comment: Although this new flatten in Scala 2.12 is most welcome for the sake of algebra, I would agree with @cchantep: the `if` statement is really another `Future` in the sequence of computations described by the for-comprehension, and should be put on the same level as the other computations. As an answer to (Scala pattern), I therefore disagree with this.

Comment: @cchantep could you elaborate? what is wrong with `flatten`?

Comment: @CyrilleCorpet what do you mean by "should be put on the same level as the other computations"? Do you prefer the code with `flatMap`? Then what is the difference between it and `map` then `flatten`? For-comprehension is just a syntactic sugar for `map` in this case.

Comment: By "on the same level", i mean as another line in the for block. I agree that all this boils down to the same, when using monadic laws and syntactic sugar. However, as a scala pattern, it is more readable to see the code as a sequence of delayed computations, each waiting for the previous one to finish. The flatten solution seems more convoluted in terms of workflow: "compute a, then b then c, which will allow me to describe another computation. By the way, you have to wait for that one to compute too". However, I also fully agree that this is mostly a personal view.

Comment: @CyrilleCorpet I see your point now. *Personally* I prefer the `flatMap` version. I think it's quite straightforward and more generic than particularities of the for-syntax. Anyway, will you write another answer with the refactored for-comprehension?

Comment: The flatMap alternative is indicated to better understand that when composing on some existing Future with a new result being another Future, then `flatMap` or `->` (in for) must be used, rather than raising the new Future in `map` or `yield` (with lead to the Future of Future situation, not necessarily as far as I can see there)